# How to change object value in array with objects with if/else in JS

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback

I have an array with objects. I need to find item with current name and change it.

```
const example = [
    {
      id: '1234',
      desc: 'sample1',
      items: [
         itemsName: [
          { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
          { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' }
         ],
         id: 888,
       ]
      },    
    {
        id: '3456',
        desc: 'sample2',
      items: [
         itemsName: [
          { id: 1, name: 'name2' },
          { id: 2, name: 'testItem3' }
         ],
         id: 889,
       ]
    },
```

I try to do in this way, but it's not working.
I get construction like (5)

```
[Array(1), Array(1)]
```

instead of

```
[{…}, {…}]


const findName = (name, changedName) => {
 const result = example?.map((group) =>
      group.items.map((group) =>
        group.itemsName?.map((i) => {
          if (i.name === name) return i.name === changedName;
          return null;
        })
      )
    );
}

findName('name1', 'name2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let findName1 = (name, changedName) => {
 const result = example?.map((group) =>
      group.items.map((group) =>
        group.itemsName?.map((i) => {
          if (i.name === name) return i.name = changedName;
          return null;
        })
      )
    );
}
```

This will work with following object (your object declaration seems to be wrong)

```
const example = [
    {
      id: '1234',
      desc: 'sample1',
      items: [
         {itemsName: [
          { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
          { id: 2, name: 'testItem2' }
         ],
         id: 888,}
       ]
      },    
    {
        id: '3456',
        desc: 'sample2',
      items: [
         {itemsName: [
          { id: 1, name: 'name2' },
          { id: 2, name: 'testItem3' }
         ],
         id: 889,}
       ]
    }]
```